# Chrome packaged app maximized messing with content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a test project, a chrome packaged app. In html/css I put the bar style as width: 100%, but when I maximize my app it just go like the half of the screen.

Here some screenshot:
[image: windowed]

[image: FullScreen]

That first bar is the problem, its width: 100% but it isnt working.
My html of that section:

```
    <section id="main" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div id='jqxWidget' style="width: 100%;">
            <div id='jqxMenu' style='visibility: hidden; margin-left: 5px; width:100%;'>
                <ul>
                    <li>Vendas
                        <ul style="height: 60px;">
                            <li id="AbrirVenda">Abrir Venda</li>
                            <li id="ConsultarVendas">Consultar Vendas</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Produtos
                        <ul style="height: 30px;">
                            <li id="ConsultarProdutos">Consultar Produtos</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Sair">Sair</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How does it appear if you load the .html page in Chrome? Have you specified <!DOCTYPE HTML> (if not you're in quirks mode). What is the CSS? You'l also likely have more success getting help or figuring it out if you reduce the sample as much as possible -- keep taking things out to narrow down the problem.

Comment: You are right, the problem was in the jqxMenu, it was setting the width to 600. I changed to 100% and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the javascript that created the menu. It was messing with the width, setting it to 600.

My bad.